# Xen not starting on Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos7, xen

I am trying to install xen on Centos 7 following this [guide](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/Xen4QuickStart).

When I run the command "xl info" the following error appears:

```
xc: error: Could not obtain handle on privileged command interface (2 = No such file or directory): Internal error
libxl: error: libxl.c:116:libxl_ctx_alloc: cannot open libxc handle: No such file or directory
cannot init xl context
```

In the followed guide it says that I should have the following line in module 2 and in mine is not present even thought it clearly says it's a bug on Centos 6.I don't know if this is related or not.

```
title CentOS (3.4.46-8.el6.centos.alt.x86_64)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /xen.gz dom0_mem=1024M,max:1024M loglvl=all guest_loglvl=all
    module /vmlinuz-3.4.46-8.el6.centos.alt.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_xen01-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_xen01/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=uk rd_NO_MD LANG=en_GB rd_LVM_LV=vg_xen01/lv_root SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
    module /initramfs-3.4.46-8.el6.centos.alt.x86_64.img
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server booted into the Xen kernel? If you run *uname -a* you should see something like 3.4.46-8.el6.centos.**alt**.x86_64. (The 'alt' indicates the Xen kernel.)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it requires mutiboot2 which RH aren't including because of security issues.

Google your message. You'll find it.